# Elasticsearch with fluent doesn't add logs to the new rollover index

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I'm using Elastic Search with Fluent and I set up a ILM for the indices. I have the following policy:

```
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "min_age": "0ms",
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_age": "2d",
            "max_size": "50mb",
            "max_docs": 50
          },
          "set_priority": {
            "priority": 100
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "2m",
        "actions": {
          "delete": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the first index it works fine, but my problem is when the new rollover index is created, it still adds the logs to the initial index. Any ideas what I got wrong? I would like the logs to be added to the last index created.

fluent.conf

```
<match *.**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearch
    port 9200
    logstash_format false
    index_name fluentd-log-000001
    type_name access_log
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 5s
  </store>

  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```

template

```
PUT _template/fluentd-template
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "fluentd*"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "index.lifecycle.name": "fluentd-policy",
    "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": "fluentd"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {},
    "_meta": {},
    "properties": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this thread help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69395179/4604579 ?

Comment: sadly, no, i provided an index_name in fluent.conf, but I have the same problem, the logs are appended to the old index

Comment: Can you add the relevant Fluentd configuration too please?

Comment: sure, I edited the description

Comment: You should probably remove `-000001` from your index name. ILM manages that sequence number automatically and I think you also need to add `enable_ilm true`

Comment: if i don't add a number at the end of the index name, i get this error:
"index name [fluentd-log] does not match pattern '^.*-\d+$'", it requires an incrementable value

Comment: Since the configured rollover_alias is `fluentd` your index name must be `index_name fluentd`. Hence no need to add `enable_ilm true` as everything is managed on ES side, i.e. you have a policy + an index template set up so all is good

Comment: yes, the policy and template works alright, but if I set index_name fluentd, it conflicts with the rollover_alias fluentd, because they have the same name

Comment: That's the whole point of ILM, you write to an alias (i.e. `fluentd`) and ILM takes care of rolling the underlying index, you don't have to care about this. As far as Fluentd is concerned, `fluentd` is an index name and as far as ES is concerned `fluentd` is an alias

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this specific part of your `fluentd.conf` configuration:

```
  index_name fluentd-log-000001
```

You're explicit specifying which index should receive the logs: `fluentd-log-000001`. That's the reason why `fluentd` is sending always to the same index (take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/elasticsearch#index_name-optional)).

One nice approach that you can do is: just let `fluentd` create the index for you and remove the `rollover_alias` from your template (it's not going to be necessary anymore). Then, add the following parameters to your `fluentd.conf` file:

```
  ilm_policy_id <your-ilm-policy-name>
  template_name <your-index-template-name>
  logstash_format true
  logstash_prefix fluentd-log
  logstash_dateformat %Y.%m.%d
```

When [logstash_format](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/elasticsearch#logstash_format-optional) is true, it supersedes the `index_name` option. With the configuration above, your new indexes will be created with a date suffix just like the following:

```sh
fluentd-log-2022.02.25
```

All new indexes will follow the ILM policy and the index template specified.